# exec in stored procedure will get the benefits of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, execute

if i put something

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @Query = 'select * from  subscriber   
                where sbs_userid = ' + cast(@UserID as varchar) + '
          and SBS_Status in (select statusFlag from #tmpStatusFlag) 
          and SBS_SourceFlag  in (select sourceFlag from #tmpSourceFlag)' 

IF (@FirstName !='')
    SET @Query = @Query + ' and  SBS_FirstName like ''%' + @FirstName + '%'''
IF(@LastName !='')
   SET @Query = @Query + ' and  SBS_LastName like ''%' + @LastName + '%'''
IF(@Phone !='')
   SET @Query = @Query + ' and  SBS_WorkPhone like ''%' + @Phone + '%'''
IF(@EmaiAdderess !='')
   SET @Query = @Query + ' and  SBS_EmailAddress like ''%' + @EmaiAdderess + '%'''
 IF(@City !='')
   SET @Query = @Query + ' and  SBS_City like ''%' + @City + '%'''   
IF(@SubListId !='-1')
   SET @Query = @Query + ' and  SBS_SubListId like ''%' + @SubListId + '%'''


SET @Query = @Query + ' order by SBS_CreationDate desc'

EXEC (@Query)
```

in my stored procedure .

**my question is still i get the benefits of stored procedure or is it a wrong approach**

i never use this but my Team Leader used this to speed up the stored proceure . is it ok ?

**EDITED**

IF we use **sp_executesql** instead of **exec** then we can take the benefits of stored procedure.and is this ok with this ?

Comment: This looks wide open to a SQL injection attack at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You would need to use [`EXEC sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx) to get the advantages of parameterisation (plan reuse - protection from SQL injection).

These leading wild card searches are going to be expensive anyway. Have you considered Full Text Indexing?

Following the edit

> If we use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec` then we can take the benefits
>   of stored procedure.and is this ok with this ?

Not *all* the benefits of stored procedures. A couple of advantages that stored procedures would still have over `sp_executesql` would be that you could then use ownership chaining and only need to grant `exec` permissions on the stored procedure rather than `select` on the underlying objects. Additionally having static stored procedures rather than dynamic SQL strings can make it easier to find dependant objects when refactoring the database.

However in your case you would need 64 separate procedures for each combination of presence/absence for the 6 optional parameters and this number grows exponentially as more optional parameters are added.

See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL Version for SQL 2005 and Earlier](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) for a thorough discussion of this topic.